# SplObjectStorage doesn't work with String, what to do?

Tags: php, spl

Someone has suggested to e to use SplObjectStorage to keep track of a set of unique things. Great, except it doesn't work with strings. An error says " SplObjectStorage::attach() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in fback.php on line 59"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`SplObjectStorage`](http://php.net/manual/class.splobjectstorage.php) is what its name says: a storage class for storing objects. In contrast to some other programming languages `strings` are not objects in PHP, they are, well, strings ;-). It therefore makes no sense to store strings in a `SplObjectStorage` - even if you wrap your strings in an object of class `stdClass`.

The best way to store a collection of unique strings si to use arrays (as hashtables) with the string as the key as well as the value (as suggested by [Ian Selby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501726/splobjectstorage-doesnt-work-with-string-what-to-do/1501977#1501977)).

```
$myStrings = array();
$myStrings['string1'] = 'string1';
$myStrings['string2'] = 'string2';
// ...
```

You could however wrap this functionality into a custom class:

```
class UniqueStringStorage // perhaps implement Iterator
{
    protected $_strings = array();

    public function add($string)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($string, $this->_strings)) {
            $this->_strings[$string] = $string;
        } else {
            //.. handle error condition "adding same string twice", e.g. throw exception
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return $this->_strings;
    }

    // ... 
}
```

By the way you san simulate the behavior of `SplObjectStorage` for PHP < 5.3.0 and to get a better understanding of what it does.

```
$ob1 = new stdClass();
$id1 = spl_object_hash($ob1);
$ob2 = new stdClass();
$id2 = spl_object_hash($ob2);
$objects = array(
    $id1 => $ob1,
    $id2 => $ob2
);
```

`SplObjectStorage` stores a unique hash for each instance (like [`spl_object_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/function.spl-object-hash.php)) to 
 be able to identify object instances. As I said above: a string is not an object at all, it therefore does not have an instance hash. A string's uniqueness can be checked by comparing the string values - two strings are equal when they contain the same set of bytes.

Answer (score 5):

It's an **Object** Storage. A string is a **scalar**. So use [SplString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl-types.php).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the string in a stdClass?

```
$dummy_object = new stdClass();
$dummy_object->string = $whatever_string_needs_to_be_tracked;
$splobjectstorage->attach($dummy_object);
```

However, every object created this way would still be unique, even if the strings are identical.

If you need to worry about duplicate strings, perhaps you should be using a hash (associative array) to track them instead?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code on how to store a set of unique strings and then iterate over them? Why is it so hard in php??

Comment: Couldn't you just store them in an array?  Seems like you're complicating things a bit much ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$myStrings = array();
$myStrings[] = 'string1';
$myStrings[] = 'string2';
...

foreach ($myStrings as $string)
{
    // do stuff with your string here...
}
```

If you wanted to ensure uniqueness of strings in the array you could do a couple of things... first would be to simply use array_unique().  That, or you could create an associative array with the strings as keys as well as the values:

```
$myStrings = array();
$myStrings['string1'] = 'string1';
...
```

If you wanted to be object-oriented about this, you could do something like:

```
class StringStore
{
   public static $strings = array();

   // helper functions, etc.  You could also make the above protected static and write public functions that add things to the array or whatever
}
```

Then, in your code you can do stuff like:

```
StringStore::$strings[] = 'string1';
...
```

And iterate the same way:

```
foreach (StringStore::$strings as $string)
{
    // whatever
}
```

SplObjectStorage is for tracking unique instances of Objects, and outside of not working with strings, it's a bit overkill for what you're trying to accomplish (in my opinion).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Or Maybe just instantiate your string as an object with __toString() method - that way you can have them both - object and ability to use it as string (var_dump, echo)..