# Associative Array versus SplObjectStorage

Tags: php, oop, associative-array, spl

I'm working on code to manage a collection of unique objects.  The first prototype of this code utilises an associative array, basically as that's the way I've always done it.

However, I'm also keen on taking advantage of functionality that's been added to more modern versions of PHP such as `[SplObjectStorage][1]` for doing this instead, partly as a learning experience, partly because it's bound to offer advantages (benchmarks I've seen suggest that `SplObjectStorage` can be faster than arrays in a lot of cases).

The current implementation has an associative array that I check with `in_array()` to see if an object is already in the array before adding a new object to it.

The big problem I can see with `SplObjectStorage` is that it doesn't seem (at first glance) to support key/value associative array behaviour, and can only be treated as an indexed array. However, the documentation for the newer features of PHP isn't up to the standards of the documentation of more established parts of the language and I might simply be missing something.

Can I use `SplObjectStorage` in place of an associative array? If so, how do I define the key when adding a new object?  More importantly, what are the relative advantages and disadvantages of `SplObjectStorage` when compared to associative arrays?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SplObjectStorage doesn't work with String, what to do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501726/splobjectstorage-doesnt-work-with-string-what-to-do)

Comment: @ajreal: I don't think my question is all that similar to the one you indicated.

Comment: Took a closer look, but still don't see how my problem (Can you use SplObjectStorage in place of an **associative** array and if so what are the benefits and drawbacks?) is a duplicate of that one (Why can't I put strings in an SplObjectStorage?)

Comment: I think the question has suggested if you want to do associate array, then use the spl object hash, and attach to spl storage object. Drawback? is troublesome. The benefits of spl storage object is because is using index key (see the implementation only use next,prev to advancing the pointer).And putting back to associate key is just defeat the purpose. This is what I thinking.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You shouldn't see the `SplObjectStorage` as a key-value store, but merely **a set of objects**. Something is in the set or not, but its **position is not important**.

The "key" of an element in the `SplObjectStorage` is in fact the hash of the object. It makes it that it is not possible to add multiple copies of the same object instance to an `SplObjectStorage`, so you don't have to check if a copy already exists before adding.

However, in `PHP 5.4` there is a new method called `getHash()` which you can override that will return the "hash" of the object. This - in a sense - returns/set the key so you can allow it to store under different conditions.

The main advantage of `SplObjectStorage` is the fact that you gain lots of methods for dealing and interacting with different sets (*`contains()`, `removeAll()`, `removeAllExcept()` etc*). Its speed is marginally better, but the **memory usage is worse** than normal PHP arrays.

Comment: In my experiments splObjectStorage actually used less memory than an set of arrays storing the object's hash.

Comment: I actually ran a speed test, which has been published here: http://www.technosophos.com/content/php-splobjectstorage-v-arrays-redux

SPLObjectStorage seems to have a sweetspot of about 10,000 DOMDocuments, after which performance degrades.

Comment: Hey, maybe this is just an oversimplification of what it does, but SplObjectStore is specifically for using objects as keys, paired to some arbitrary value...and not just a set of objects.

Answer (score 13):

Results after running this [benchmark](https://github.com/technosophos/Benchmarks-PHP/blob/master/SPLObjectStorage-vs-Arrays.php) with 10,000 iterations on PHP 5.6.13:

| Type | Time to fill | Time to check | Memory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SplObjectStorage | 0.021285057068 | 0.019490000000 | 2131984 |
| Array | 0.021125078201 | 0.020912000000 | 1411440 |

`Array`s use **34% less memory** and are **about the same speed** as `SplObjectStorage`.

---

Results with PHP 7.4.27:

| Type | Time to fill | Time to check | Memory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SplObjectStorage | 0.019295692444 | 0.016039848328 | 848384 |
| Array | 0.024008750916 | 0.022011756897 | 3215416 |

`Array`s use **3.8 times more memory** and are **24% slower** than `SplObjectStorage`.

---

Results with PHP 8.1.1:

| Type | Time to fill | Time to check | Memory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SplObjectStorage | 0.009704589844 | 0.003775596619 | 768384 |
| Array | 0.014604568481 | 0.012760162354 | 3215416 |

`Array`s use **4.2 times more memory** and are **50% slower** than `SplObjectStorage`.

Comment: It's only 3% difference in time, not 50% ? And 34% instead of 50% regarding memory.

Comment: @roman Please could you explain your math here? I mean the 1.5 that you arrived at.

Comment: Given your data, I get arrays are 1% faster time to fill, 7% slower time to check, and use 34% less memory.

Comment: It would be nice to see the stats in PHP7.

Comment: @twity1337 So run the code provided in the link on an instance of PHP 7.

Comment: SplObjectStorage is actually way faster with PHP 7.3.1 and also uses less memory based on my test (100 000 iterations, 13687024 vs 31891536 for array)

Comment: I added results for PHP 7 and PHP 8.

Answer (score 1):

When all the memory allocated to array is used up, the memory allocated to it will be doubled. In this context, a collection of objects may be more effective structure.