# PHP with Spl DataStructures as replacement for multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, acl, spl

I've seen many questions on this topic, but none of them covers my case.

I am building an ACL module based on 5 classes:

1. Role
2. Privilege
3. Group
4. Wrapper(guess what it does..)Factory for the Privilege, Role and Group classes
5. AccessList Store for the groups/roles (based on usage and case)

I am thinking to use the SplQueue to store the privileges levels(mainly for the inherited privileges) So I am thinking to use a single object to store everything and do not think that the normal multi-dimensional array will be the best choice. The flow will be like [this paste](http://pastebin.com/BAbxsdYx), it is **TL;DR**.. Sorry about that.

> So my question is will the SplQueue be an overkill in my case?
>
> Should I use and alternative Spl Data Structure, and if so which one?

**EDIT**
Well I couldn't think of a good example of the usage, so lets keep to the UNIX based GBAC.

Comment: A data structure should support the use cases for the operations that are performed on it. You haven't mentioned any of them.

Comment: Well the purpose is general, give me a second to write it and will update in a sec

Comment: I think this is really overkill for small arrays. (small is under 100-1000 elements). The internal hashmap provides fast enough access mostly. SPL is good when you really need log(n) access and insert times etc.

Comment: Well I guess you're right.. The normal ACL should do the trick in any grade PHP applications. Well here goes the rep :D

Comment: I suggest you answer your own question with how you proceeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to store your data in the object form then the use the `SplObjectStorage`. The SplQueue will overkill for small array.

> SplQueue works on FIFO.

So you cann't access directly to last or near to the last and will take time.

Instead of `SplQueue` I will suggest you use the Array as you can access any element directly by array index.

You can also check the answer of this question: [Associative Array versus SplObjectStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520241/associative-array-versus-splobjectstorage)

Also you can check the the performance of SPLobjectStorage and array, [here is the code](https://github.com/technosophos/Benchmarks-PHP/blob/master/SPLObjectStorage-vs-Arrays.php).

For more [read here](http://technosophos.com/content/set-objects-php-arrays-vs-splobjectstorage).

> SplObjectStorage definitely scaled linearly. Array performance was
>   less predictable (larger standard deviation) with smaller data sets. And SplObjectStorage is indeed a better solution for storing lots of objects in a set.

So if your data is small then you should use the array otherwise use the `SplObjectStorage` for large amount of data.

Comment: Will the array have any drawbacks if the data gets bigger, to clarify:
20 roles in total, 6 Groups and 1 Page identifier(the page identifiers are used to determinate a specific part of the app)

 6x1 - Group Definitions and in-group definitions *(6x1)x20*(At least with my architecture/head) which results in 120 definitions in the storage which will grow dramatically in 100 pages app. Could there be any drawbacks if I go with arrays or SplObjectStorage. 

Thanks!

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov if you have approximate 120 data then you can use the array and if you have thousands record then use the SplObjectStorage as I have added the links in the answer. you can see the performance issues will come in array for large data and for small data the performance of SplObjectStorage will be bad then the array. now its depends on your data.

Comment: Advice me: Which approach should I go for? Using arrays and making the structure low data ready or high data ready(couldn't think of better words o say it sorry, english is not my native)

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov I suggest to you use the `SplObjectStorage` as you have describe that you have multilevel privileges and that will create a combination. so there will a lot of records so use the `SplObjectStorage`. And other things depends on your preferences.

Comment: Thanks for the attention and the detailed explaination